# f injective, g injective, $f\circ g(a) = a$ implies $f$ bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have a function $f:A \to B$ such that $f$ is injective.
We have a function $g:B \to A$ such that $g$ is injective.

From the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem we know that there exist a bijection between $A$ and $B$. Hence, $|A| = |B|$.

If we further have that $f(g(b)) = b, \forall b \in B$, does this imply that $f$ is a bijection between $A$ and $B$? Or do we also need the fact that $g(f(a)) = a, \forall a \in A$?

Answer (score 2):

If $f(g(b))=b$ for all $b$, then in particular for $b:=f(a)$ we also have $f(g(f(a))=f(a)$ for all $a$. Now, using that $f$ is injective we arrive at $g(f(a)=a$.

Answer (score 1):

The relation $\forall b \in B, f(g(b)) = b$ implies that $f$ is surjective, since for any $b\in B$, the element $g(b) \in A$ is sent to it by $f$. Thus $f$ is both an injection and a surjection, and therefore a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From the stated assumptions, it is straightforward to prove that $f$ is surjective, as follows.

Let $b \in B$. Then since $f(g(b)) = b$, $b$ is in the image of $f$.